# Не работает парсер ошибки не выдает

Tags: python, парсер

Парсер ничего не пишет хотя ошибку тоже не выдает все html теги правильные.Писал похожие парсеры с разных видео уроков но везде одна и таже проблема

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():
  URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/list/'
  HEADERS = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
  }

  response = requests.get(URL,
  headers = HEADERS)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'css-u2ayx9')
  comps = []

  for item in items:
    comps.append({
    'title': item.find('a', class_ = 'css-16v5mdi er34gjf0').get_text(strip = True)
    })

  for comp in comps:
    print(comp['title'])

parse()
```

Comment: "все html теги правильные.", зато ваш код утверждает обратное.

Comment: @СергейШ вот код дива :
<div class="css-u2ayx9"><h6 class="css-16v5mdi er34gjf0">текст</h6><p data-testid="ad-price" class="css-10b0gli er34gjf0">цена.</p></div> вроде все теги правильно написал

Comment: При выполнения кода items принимает значение [], а это говорит о том что, отсутсвуют <div class="css-u2ayx9"> в исходниках html страницы.

Comment: @СергейШ я еще раз проверил исходный код страницы и class="css-u2ayx9" class="css-16v5mdi er34gjf0" существовали и были там где нужно. Я пытался написать много парсеров по видео урокам и везде была одна и таже страница при том что все теги были в исходнике кода